# A faulty clock runs backwards and slow, covering $55$ minutes in a hour. ...

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> The clock in the maths department common room is faulty. At twenty past three on Wednesday afternoon it shows 11:25. The clock in fact goes backwards, and is a bit slow, covering 55 minutes
> every hour. The clock has a usual 12 hour dial.
>
> What time does it show at twenty past eight on the following Friday morning?

Comment: The problem tells you all you need to know: How fast the clock moves, for how long it moves, and where it begins. So it should be rather straight-forward to find the answer. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I am unsure on where to start

Comment: Look at how much time eclipsed from 3:20 PM Wednesday until 8:20 AM Friday.  Then, because the clock moves only 55 minutes per hour, calculate how much time it moved from when it showed 11:25 at 3:20 PM Wednesday

Answer (score 1):

There is a total length of 41 hours between the first and second points where we are checking the clock. If the clocks goes backwards 55 minutes every hour, then it will go $55*41=2255$ minutes or $\dfrac{2255}{60}=37$ hours $35$ minutes. This gives a time of **9:50** on Friday morning.